# Methods missing in Android studio 2.1.1 default MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1 and facing a problem.In my default MainActivity.java file i don't have onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) these two methods.i tried to type manually but it shows error.So i don't know how to fix it or what is the problem.And for this reason i cannot continue.What should i do now?

[there should be two more methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEde.jpg)

Comment: could you post your code mate, we can't imagine a solution like that !!

Comment: So just Override the methods? CTRL+O

Comment: I just added a picture ...There should be another two methods according the tutorial i am following..

Comment: You need to Override the methods from the super class .. My initial comment above doesn't change.  I suggest that you read a little into Java and method overriding if you're stumbling at this point.

Comment: Thanks..actually i've found the problem....actually i select empty activity ..i should've select basic activity too follow that tutorial bt in the older version of AS there was a blank activity i thought blank acivity is empty activity...

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you do not mind these class

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

Why do not you try to create the navigation drawer activity that is the activity that has these class

Comment: thank u for ur reply...it helped .i actually select empty activity ..i should've select basic activity too follow my tutorial bt in the older version of AS there was a blank activity i thought blank acivity is empty activity...that's it ...for this silly mistake i spend my entire day...actually this is my 2nd day with android studio...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are either extending a class or implementing an interface. The error means you haven't implemented all the necessary methods required by the interface/superclass. Not 100% sure where to click before doing the shortcut, but this can be fixed by:

- Clicking the class name(?) in the editor
- Pressing ALT+ENTER

Android Studio will then implement the method headers for you. It's up to you whether you want to implement functionality in the method body or just leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the problem....actually i select empty activity ..i should've select basic activity too follow that tutorial bt in the older version of AS there was a blank activity i thought blank acivity is empty activity..anyway thanks to everybody who tried to help me...